# how to pagination category and sub category in Codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3, categorical-data

I can't return $limit and $offset in my model in pagination in Codeigniter .It's my code that I display data from database category,sub_category and products.
my tables are :Main_Category, Category , Prosucts.

```
public function all_collection($id) {
        $this->db->select( '*' );
        $this->db->order_by( 'category.orderList', 'DESC' );
        $this->db->where( 'statusCategory', 1 );
        $this->db->where('category.category_id',$id);
        $this->db->join('category_menu','category_menu.id=category.MainCategory_id','left');
        //$this->db->where('category_menu.displayType',1);
        $this->db->where('category.parent_id',0);
        $query = $this->db->get( 'category');
        $return=array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $category)
        {
             $return[$category->category_id]=$category;
             $return[$category->category_id]->subs = $this->getSubcategory($category->category_id); // Get the categories sub categories

        }
        return $return;

    }
    public function getSubcategory($parent_id) {
        $this->db->select( '*' );
        $this->db->order_by( 'category_id', 'DESC' );
        $this->db->where('parent_id',$parent_id);
        $this->db->where( 'category.statusCategory', 1 );
        $data = $this->db->get( 'category' );
        $products=$data->result();
         $i=0;
        foreach($products as $category){
        $products[$i]->subss = $this->getProducts($category->category_id);
        $i++;
}
        return $products;
    }
    public function getProducts($cat_id){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('product.category_ids',$cat_id);
        $this->db->where('product.p_deleted_at =', 'NULL');
        $this->db->join('product_price','product_ids=product.product_id','left')->limit(1)->where('statusPrice',1)->order_by('price_id','DESC');
        $this->db->join('product_image','improduct_ids=product.product_id','left')->limit(1)->where('statusProImage',1)->order_by('image_id','DESC');
        $this->db->join('product_stock','product_stock.product_id=product.product_id','left')->limit(1)->where('statusStock',1)->order_by( 'stock_id', 'DESC' );
        $this->db->join('brand','brand_id=product.brand_ids','left');
        $query=$this->db->get('product');
        return $query->result();

    }
```